# Neo4j py2neo transaction commit duplicates node somewhere in loop

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I'm working with py2neo 3.1.2, and trying to create several nodes within a loop, and connect them all to a single node. I've got a simplified version of the code, which still demonstrates the issue:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
graph = Graph('http://localhost/db/data/', username="neo4j", password="myPassword")

tx = graph.begin()
source = Node("Source",id="test2")
for i in range(0,20):
    node = Node("Datum",id=i)
    rel = Relationship(source,"SourceOf",node)
    tx.create(rel)
tx.commit()
```

In my database, "Source" nodes have a uniqueness constraint, and the query fails because an ID is being duplicated. I've cleared the database of other "Source" nodes, so it's being duplicated within this loop. Without the uniqueness constraint, the code works, but there are two identical "Source" nodes, one related to all but one of my "Datum" nodes, and one related to a single "Datum" node.

If I don't use the transaction, and instead do this:

```
source = Node("Source",id="test2")
for i in range(0,20):
    node = Node("Datum",id=i)
    rel = Relationship(source,"SourceOf",node)
    graph.create(rel)
```

it works, but is slower than the transaction. I can keep using the `graph.create` approach instead, but I'm curious if this is a bug, or if I'm just approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I haven't been able to solve it while still using transactions, so I've just been using `graph.create()` instead